# WordPress - How do I display custom post type in page that uses category.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called 'suppliers' which is used to display a series of supplier's logos in the footer.

```
<?php $suppliers_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'suppliers', 'posts_per_page' => 7 ) ); ?>
<?php if ($suppliers_loop->have_posts()):?>
<?php while ( $suppliers_loop->have_posts() ) : $suppliers_loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $image = get_field('image');?>
    <div class="col-1-7 mobile-col-1-4">
        <a href="<?php echo(get_field('suppliers_url'))?>" target="_blank">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url'];?>" title="<?php echo $image['title'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'];?>"/>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This works well on every page of the site including other custom post type archives and categories apart from the standard WordPress category page? Where the loop returns:

```
<div class="col-1-7 mobile-col-1-4">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" title="" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
```

If I replace `echo $image['title']` with `the_title()` it returns:

```
<div class="col-1-7 mobile-col-1-4">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" title="Digital White Ink" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-1-7 mobile-col-1-4">
    <a href="" target="_blank">
        <img src="" title="Environment" alt=""/>
    </a>
</div>
etc..
```

These returned titles are pages and other post types (some of which are in the bin)? Can anyone shed any light on what on earth is going wrong and how to rectify it?

Comment: Do you have a `global $post;` above this code somewhere? Many WP functions that do something with the “current” post in any kind of loops need this.

Comment: No.  `global $post` doesn't appear anywhere. The template uses exactly the same template parts (loop, pagination, header, footer etc..) as other custom post types which display the suppliers correctly.

Comment: Try passing the current post id to get_field directly.

Answer (score -1):

It is better not to change the php file in the wordpress. The code will be back to default if the theme updated.

My suggestion is change the CSS using "custom css plugin". Sorry for my bad english and thank you.

Comment: I'm developing the theme so theres no worries about it defaulting back to anything.